# pick a random number not in a list

Tags: python, arrays, random

I have a list:

```
> S = [1,8,93,3,8]
```

I need to pick a random number that is not in the list but within the max range of value. I am more concerned about time complexity O(n). The S could be a pretty big list.

```
import random

S=[1,8,93,3,8]
m = max(S)
for x in xrange(m):
  rand = random.randint(1,m)
  if rand not in S:
      print rand
  else:
      print "Number - %d found in the array" % rand 
      break
```

I did not try list comprehension

Comment: What's wrong with `m + 1`?

Comment: Or, if it's a `list` of integers, and the random number doesn't have to be an integer, `0.5` would work.

Comment: You are right. I need to add m+1 for the range of numbers

Comment: No, I mean, why not use `m + 1` for a number guaranteed not to be in `S`?

Comment: Can you clarify what distribution you want to draw the numbers from?

Comment: True.Smart question. But the question is about traversing through a list that could  be N numbers.

Comment: Why did you make that edit? That's not what I was talking about at all. `random.randint()` is inclusive anyway. I mean, if you have `m = max(S)`, all you need to do to get a number that isn't in `S`  is `m + 1`. That's guaranteed not to be in `S`.

Comment: I don't see why you need to traverse anything. Once more, can you explain why `m+1` or `0.5` wouldn't be suitable?

Comment: Are you trying to generate a random **integer** that is not in the list and **less than the max integer** in the list?

Comment: 0.5 is not acceptable the return values should be an integer. Question is about traversing not about the max value +1

Comment: Why is the question about traversing? Is there some other component to this question that you haven't told us?

Comment: Why so much negative points for this question. I dont understand

Comment: Probably because it took 20 minutes to actually say what you were looking for.

Comment: I am very, very confused. What does _taversing_ have to do with _picking a random integer_? Could you please rephrase **clearly** what it is exactly that you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: @N.Wouda - I need to find random value that is not in the list and the value should be less than the max value in the list.

Comment: @N.Wouda - Probably something like `random.choice(list(set(range(min(S), max(S)+1))-set(S)))`, but prematurely optimized.

Comment: People will penalize the asker just like that. Wow.

Comment: @Paddy are you surprised? An unclear question is a _bad_ question, simple as that.

Comment: @N.Wouda - Thanks for emphasizing. I will be careful.

Comment: The hovertext on the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". In case it matters I didn't vote up or down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the `list` consists of integers and any number is acceptable:

```
S = [1,8,93,3,8]
number = 0.5
```

If the number must be an integer:

```
S = [1,8,93,3,8]
number = max(S) + 1
```

If the number must be an arbitrary integer between the largest and smallest elements in the `list`:

```
S = [1,8,93,3,8]
number = next(iter(set(range(min(S)+1, max(S))) - set(S)))
```

If the number must be a psuedorandom integer between the largest and smallest elements in the `list`:

```
import random
S = [1,8,93,3,8]
number = random.choice(list(set(range(min(S)+1, max(S)))-set(S)))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the simplest thing I could come up with:

```
import random

S=[1,8,93,3,8]
m = max(S)

not_in_S = random.choice([x for x in range(m) if x not in S])
```