# how to split the string in one column and compare it with other column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, split

Let's say I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Paste_Values AB_IDs AC_IDs    AD_IDs
AE-1001-4 AB-1001-0  AC-1001-4 AD-1001-2
AE-1964-7 AB-1964-2  AC-1964-7 AD-1964-1
AE-2211-1 AB-2211-1  AC-2211-3 AD-2211-2
AE-2182-4 AB-2182-4  AC-2182-7 AD-2182-5
```

I would like to split the column Paste_value into AE and 1001-4 and compare the 1001-4 is in Ab_IDS by split Ab IDS by AB and 100-4

if 1001-4 is same in the Paste value and AB_IDS we need create a new columns called AB_Match and return "Match" in that row

AS produce get followed compare Paste_value with AC_ids and create new column called AC_match if its match it show have "match" in it

### result should look like this :

```
Paste_Values AB_IDs AC_IDs    AD_IDs   AB_match Ac_match AD_match
AE-1001-4 AB-1001-0  AC-1001-4 AD-1001-2             Match
AE-1964-7 AB-1964-2  AC-1964-7 AD-1964-1             Match
AE-2211-1 AB-2211-1  AC-2211-3 AD-2211-2   Match
AE-2182-4 AB-2182-4  AC-2182-7 AD-2182-5   Match
```

I have a new  question with the same Problem

### 1.I have to create a new column called new_Paste_value in the last digit of paste value should not  match with any of the AB_IDS, AC_IDs, and AD_IDs I need to generate a random number which the last digit should not match all three IDS Last digit number

#### My result looks like this

```
  Paste_Values     AB_IDs     AC_IDs     AD_IDs AB_match AC_match AD_match  new_p_v
   AE-1001-4  AB-1001-0  AC-1001-4  AD-1001-2             Match             AE-1001-5
   AE-1964-7  AB-1964-2  AC-1964-7  AD-1964-1             Match             AE-1964-4
   AE-2211-1  AB-2211-1  AC-2211-3  AD-2211-2    Match                      AE-2211-8
   AE-2182-4  AB-2182-4  AC-2182-7  AD-2182-5    Match                      AE-2182-6
```

Comment: This is R so why did you tag it with pandas and python

Comment: @d_kennetz sorry wrong type the question I need the solution in python now I edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with

```
s=df.apply(lambda x : x.str.split('-',1).str[-1])
s=s.drop('Paste_Values',1).eq(s.Paste_Values,0).replace({False:'',True:'Match'})
s.columns=s.columns.str.replace('IDs','match')
df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
df
Out[221]: 
  Paste_Values     AB_IDs     AC_IDs     AD_IDs AB_match AC_match AD_match
0    AE-1001-4  AB-1001-0  AC-1001-4  AD-1001-2             Match         
1    AE-1964-7  AB-1964-2  AC-1964-7  AD-1964-1             Match         
2    AE-2211-1  AB-2211-1  AC-2211-3  AD-2211-2    Match                  
3    AE-2182-4  AB-2182-4  AC-2182-7  AD-2182-5    Match
```

Comment: thanks for the answer could you please check the question again I need more clear anwer

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
m=df.filter(like='ID').apply(lambda x: x.str.split('-',n=1).str[1])
m.columns=[i.split('_')[0]+'_Match' for i in m.columns]
```

---

```
m[:]=np.where(m.eq(df.Paste_Values.str.split('-',n=1).str[1],axis=0),'Match','')
df_final=df.join(m)
```

---

```
  Paste_Values     AB_IDs     AC_IDs     AD_IDs AB_Match AC_Match AD_Match
0    AE-1001-4  AB-1001-0  AC-1001-4  AD-1001-2             Match         
1    AE-1964-7  AB-1964-2  AC-1964-7  AD-1964-1             Match         
2    AE-2211-1  AB-2211-1  AC-2211-3  AD-2211-2    Match                  
3    AE-2182-4  AB-2182-4  AC-2182-7  AD-2182-5    Match
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I have new question  could  you see  it once again

Comment: @vka a new question should be posted as a separate question. You can ping me the link once you have done that. Thanks

Comment: sure I will post the separate question

Comment: is this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56481656/how-to-split-the-string-in-one-column-and-compare-it-with-other-column-and-creat

Comment: @vka i wasnt available on the system yesterday. However you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34371542/pick-a-random-number-not-in-a-list